# Xcode iOS Simulator iPhone 6 and 6 Plus Scaling Error

Tags: ios, xcode, scale

When I run iOS Simulator on iPhone 6 and 6 plus, my app is always scaled down. On iPhone 5 it is okay. How can I fix this problem? Here is an image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9rIc.jpg

Comment: That image isn't helpful in understanding your issue. What do you mean it is "always scaled down"?

Comment: @rmaddy It always is sized down. In the image, there is lots of space on the right and left. I want the objects to be scaled up so it is big enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kush Patel Here issue About `AutoSizing` Of your `Button`. Set `autolayout` to Your View Else Set Autosizing to Your View.

Another method Like as set `autoresizingMask`to Your Button or Imageview. like as

```
self.yourbutton.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```